# How to reference the class present in an element in Sass or Less

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm trying to use a CSS preprocessor to reduce some duplication when writing the code. In my HTML, these elements will only have one class. I want to go from something like

```
a.USA{background: url('images/USA.gif'};
a.EUR{background: url('images/EUR.gif'};
a.JPN{background: url('images/JPN.gif'};
```

to the following pseudo-code:

```
a.USA,a.EUR,a.JPN{
  background: url('images/[THE-NAME-OF-THE-ACTUAL-CLASS-USED].gif');
}
```

How could I do this in LESS or Sass (doesn't matter which)?

Comment: No, as far as I am aware you can't group these into a single CSS selector. In Less/Sass you can make it a single block but the compiled CSS output would still be the same as your original one.

Comment: @Harry the duplication problem I was asking about was with the hand typed code, not the compiled CSS. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @MikeEng: Ok. If that is the case then it can be done with both Sass and Less.

Comment: @Harry Great, so how would one do it with LESS? I couldn't find anything like it in an initial review of LESS documentation.

Comment: But you've already accepted an answer (with Sass). Are you looking for an example with Less? If you need I can post an answer with both Sass and Less versions.

Comment: @Harry just curious about how to do it in Less if that is indeed an option, but no big deal. Things are a little out of order now since I accepted that answer before we clarified the confusion about compiled code versus typed code.

Comment: Since the for-each loop is an often asked about feature, I've added the example in the documentation section - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/less/5424/loops/19324/writing-a-for-each-loop#t=201608121143333518162. See if it helps (and if it does, don't forget to upvote the example :D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Harry mentioned, the ouput would be the same. But its possible with sass. The example here is something you search:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive